# Grails injection of g:select and jQuery handler

Tags: jquery, grails, gsp

I have the following Grails (2.3.6) POGO:

```
class Pet {
    Long id
    String name
    PetType type
}
```

And the following controller:

```
class PetController {
    def index() {
        List<Pet> pets = PetLoader.loadAllPets()
        render(
            view: "listPets",
            model: [
                pets: pets
            ]
        )
    }

    def loadPet() {
        Long petId = params.petId   // Pet#id
        // Do stuff with the 'petId'.
    }
)
```

And in the body of the respective `listPets.gsp`:

```
<body>
    <h1>Select a pet to edit below:</h1>

    <g:select id="pets"
        name="pets"
        from="${pets}"
        value="${pet.name}"
        optionKey="id" />

    <g:javascript>
        var ajaxAction = "${createLink(controller:'pet',action:'loadPet')}"
        $("#pets").on('change', function() {
            $.get(
                url: ajaxAction,
                data: $("#pets").val(),
                success: function(data, status) {
                    alert("Success!\n" + data);
                },
                dataType: "json"
            );
        });
    </g:javascript>
</body>
```

When I run this code, I get an empty `<g:select>` that is obviously not injected/configured correctly.  What I want to do is this:

1. When the page loads, the entire `users` list gets injected into the `<select id="pets">` drop-down and displays the `Pet#name` String as the option text; then
2. When the user selects a new `Pet` from the drop-down (in the UI), the jQuery handler fires an asynch call to `loadPet`; then
3. Inside `loadPet`, I need acccess to the `Pet#id` of the selected value in the drop down, via the `params` object, so that I can do other stuff with that pet id in the backend

I'm having a tough time seeing the forest through the trees here. I'm definitely sure that I botched the `<g:select>` tag. But I may also need to make changes to the controller and/or jQuery script.  So I ask: What changes do I need to my code so that the select is populated with `Pet#name`, but, when `loadPets` is called from the jQuery, I have access to the `Pet#id` from the `params`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying your code slightly, here is an example that (I believe) does what you intended. Here are the key changes:

1. Within `g:select`, use `optionValue` and `optionKey` to control the
   display string and underlying `<option>` value.  For more detail and
   examples, see: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html
2. Your jQuery code uses the `.get()` shorthand, but `.ajax()` parameter syntax. 
   Either could be made work, but there are differences in the function parameters. See:
   http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/
3. I included a CDN link to jQuery.  This is useful for quick tests, but there are a variety of other ways to include the jQuery library (and you may already have this configured in your project)
4. `createLink` is wrapped with `raw()` to ensure that the URL produced is not escaped.

**Updated Code:**

No changes to `Pet` or `PetController`

`listPets.gsp`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Select a pet to edit below:</h1>

    <g:select id="pets"
        name="pets"
        from="${pets}"
        optionKey="id"
        optionValue="name" />

    <g:javascript>
        var ajaxAction = '${raw(createLink(controller:'pet',action:'loadPet'))}';
        $("#pets").on('change', function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxAction,
                data: { petId: $("#pets").val() },
                success: function(data, status) {
                    alert("Success!\n" + data);
                }
            });
        });
    </g:javascript>

</body>
</html>
```